# Nginx - wordpress in a subdirectory, what data should be passed?

Tags: php, wordpress, path, nginx, webserver

I've tried so many different things. The point I'm at right now is this:

```
location ^~ /wordpress {
    alias /var/www/example.com/wordpress;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /wordpress/index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/wordpress)(/.*)$;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/example.com/wordpress/index.php;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

Right now, all resources as far as I can tell (images, etc) are loading correctly. And `http://www.example.com/wordpress` loads wordpress, but a page that says "page not found". (Wordpress is in use for this though). If I try any post urls I get the same result, "page not found". So I know the problem is that wordpress isn't obtaining the data about the path or something. Another potential problem is that if I run `example.com/wp-admin.php` then it will still run `index.php`.

What data needs to be passed? What may be going wrong here?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Since your location alias end match, you should just use root.  Also, not *everything* is routed through index.php on wordpress afaik.  Also, unless you know you need path info, you probably dont.  I think you want something like:

```
location @wp {
  rewrite ^/wordpress(.*) /wordpress/index.php?q=$1;
}

location ^~ /wordpress {
    root /var/www/example.com;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @wp;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }
}
```

or if you really do need path info (urls look like /wordpress/index.php/foo/bar):

```
location ^~ /wordpress {
    root /var/www/example.com;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /wordpress/index.php;

    location ~ \.php {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.*\.php)(.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }
}
```

EDIT: Updated first server{} to strip initial /wordpress from uri and pass remainder as q param

EDIT2: Named locations are only valid at server level

Comment: I try that (your first one) but I keep getting the 404 not found wordpress page. It might have to do with me moving the blog from a different domain to a domain with a subdirectory.

Comment: I think maybe wordpress needs the initial /wordpress stripped.  Edited the first server to do that.

Comment: That's the definitive answer!!! I've used the first solution with 'location /wordpress' in place of 'location ^~ /wordpress' and 'alias' in place of 'root'.

Comment: first solution worked perfect first time - thank you! :)

Comment: Your second solution works perfectly, including with the WP-API plugin URLs. Thanks!

Comment: Is @wp a variable of some kind?

Comment: It's a named location, defined a few lines above where it's referenced

Answer (score 15):

Dude, this will work for for a wordpress blog in a subdirectory of the magento root folder!

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my-site.co.uk;
    rewrite / $scheme://www.$host$request_uri permanent; ## Forcibly prepend a www
}

server {
    listen 80 default;
    client_max_body_size 8M;
    ## SSL directives might go here
    server_name www.my-site.co.uk; ## Domain is here twice so server_name_in_redirect will favour the www
    root /var/www/my-site/magento;

    location / {
        index index.html index.php; ## Allow a static html file to be shown first
       try_files $uri $uri/ @handler; ## If missing pass the URI to Magento's front handler
       expires 30d; ## Assume all files are cachable
    }

    location  /wordpress {
              index index.php index.html index.htm;
             try_files $uri $uri/ /wordpress/index.php;
             }

    ## These locations would be hidden by .htaccess normally
    location ^~ /app/                { deny all; }
    location ^~ /includes/           { deny all; }
    location ^~ /lib/                { deny all; }
    location ^~ /media/downloadable/ { deny all; }
    location ^~ /pkginfo/            { deny all; }
    location ^~ /report/config.xml   { deny all; }
    location ^~ /var/                { deny all; }

    location /var/export/ { ## Allow admins only to view export folder
        auth_basic           "Restricted"; ## Message shown in login window
        auth_basic_user_file htpasswd; ## See /etc/nginx/htpassword
        autoindex            on;
    }

    location  /. { ## Disable .htaccess and other hidden files
        return 404;
    }


    location @handler { ## Magento uses a common front handler
        rewrite / /index.php;
    }

    location ~ .php/ { ## Forward paths like /js/index.php/x.js to relevant handler
        rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
    }

    location ~ .php$ { ## Execute PHP scripts
        if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; } ## Catch 404s that try_files miss

        expires        off; ## Do not cache dynamic content
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param  HTTPS $fastcgi_https;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_CODE default; ## Store code is defined in administration > Configuration > Manage Stores
        fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
        include        fastcgi_params; ## See /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params
    }
}
```

Comment: If anyone want's the core config file I'm using for Nginx with this site config just let me know.

Comment: works for me, im not using Magento but that block for wordpress is helpful. thx

Comment: Thumbs up from me ! Very simple and straightforward, that wordpress part and worked perfectly for my site. I found the example at codex.wordress.com to be very complex !

Comment: @AntonySmith Can you post the core config of magento and wordpress in subfolder.I can't figure it out exactly and been searching since week.

Comment: This should be the accepted solution!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and this is what fixed it for me:

1. Open the NGINX configuration file for your site. Inside of the server block, add the path to your root directory and set the priority order for files:

   ```
   root /mnt/www/www.domainname.com;
   index  index.php index.html index.htm;
   ```
2. Create an empty location block *before* all your other location blocks:

   ```
   location /latest {
   # Nothing in here; this is to avoid redirecting for this location
   }
   ```
3. Commend out the root directory in your location / block and add the redirection so it looks like this:

   ```
   location / {
   # root   /mnt/www/www.domainname.com;
   index  index.php index.html index.htm;
   rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://www.domainname.com/latest/$1 redirect;
   }
   ```
4. Make sure that your location ~ .php$ block points its root to

   ```
   root /mnt/www/www.domainname.com;
   ```

This fixed it for me.